# Edge following algorithm for OpenCV (c++)

Tags: opencv, tracking, point, edge-detection

In this [book](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=eSu5I9pU3rUC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=follow%20edge%20around%20object%20image%20processing&source=bl&ots=f90zcoSb0q&sig=4mXEKNfG92kJkDXVDCaaJ6sCzNE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ggKRVeP8LsPKmwXO9YJw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=follow%20edge%20around%20object%20image%20processing&f=false) and this [pdf](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/BANDB/LIB/bandb4_4.pdf) I found a simple "edge following algorithm". This algorithm takes a seed-point on a edge as argument. Then the edge is tracked around the object until the seed-point is reached again. Is there any algorithm available to do this in OpenCV? Why is it so hard to find anything like this in other Threads. For me the idea to follow an edge seems reasonable. Are there big problems with this technique I don't see yet?

Comment: What's wrong with findContours with CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE?

Comment: Tell me if I totally missunderstood it. What I am looking for is a function that takes a seed-point on an edge around an object as argument and then follows the contour. That should happen not happen on a binary image but on a grayscale image. Is that possible with CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE?